# How can I create sequence diagram by using mscgen through doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard, mscgen

Graviz is working fine with doxygen, but I am having hard time using mscgen. In doxywizard I have set the mscgen_path to the mscgen bin folder. However the output html does not show any sequence diagram.